# what does the method Mojo.getLog() do?

Tags: java, maven, methods

I wonder why nowhere is it said how getLog() in maven really works?
It would be nice if someone can describe the main task of this method in just a few sentences.

Comment: I don't know that method. Could you include what class (full qualified name including package name) provides that method?

Comment: Could you be more specific about where you call `getLog()` i.e. which class etc.

Comment: okay, sorry for this. here's an example: public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {
        this.getLog().info(this.message);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been mentioned in Apache common logging API DOC refer to this link http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.html#getLog(java.lang.Class)

Comment: Mojo.getLog() returns an instance of `org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log`, whereas commons-logging's LogFactory return an instance of `org.apache.commons.logging.Log`, so your link wrong.

Comment: @blackbuild if you checked correctly i posted my answer before he posted the class which instanciates it :)

Comment: Ah, ok. but ist was close :) Still your answer doesn't match the question anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documenation?

> http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/Mojo.html#getLog()

You can find your answer there.